# Extracting Column Details & Type from Schema Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

i am using AWS EMR v5.29.0 Spark v2.4.4 and Scala v2.11.12.

i am reading a file with infer schema method and creating dataframe with column names and datatype of column name with below code

```
val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","header"->"true")).csv("s3://bucket-name/File_Name.csv")
val columnList = df.schema.fields.map(field => (field.name, field.dataType.typeName)).toList.toDF("column_name","datatype")
```

when i do df.printSchema() the output is as below.

```
df.printSchema()

Output:

root
 |-- ABC|EFG|IJK|LMN: string (nullable = true)
```

When i am doing columnList.show()
the output is coming as below

```
+--------------------+--------+
|         column_name|datatype|
+--------------------+--------+
|ABC|EFG|IJK|LMN     |  string|
+--------------------+--------+
```

where as the output required is like below.

```
+---------------+--------+
|column_name    |datatype|
+---------------+--------+
|ABC            |string  |
|EFG            |string  |
|IJK            |string  |
|LMN            |string  |
+---------------+--------+
```

Regards

mahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
scala> df.select(split($"column_name","\\|").as("column_name"),$"datatype").select(explode($"column_name"),$"datatype").show(false)
+---+--------+
|col|datatype|
+---+--------+
|ABC|string  |
|EFG|string  |
|IJK|string  |
|LMN|string  |
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **`split`** the column `|` to create an **array** and **explode** the df dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

columnList.withColumn("column_name",explode(split(col("column_name"),"\\|"))).
show()
//+-----------+--------+
//|column_name|datatype|
//+-----------+--------+
//|        ABC|  string|
//|        EFG|  string|
//|        IJK|  string|
//|        LMN|  string|
//+-----------+--------+
```